What are $f$ and $g$ such that $a_n = \frac {f(n)} {g(n)}$ diverges, $f$ and $g$ are strictly increasing, yet $f \neq \Omega (g)$?
I am trying to find $2$ functions $f: \mathbb{R}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$ and $g : \mathbb{R}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$ where $f$ and $g$ are strictly increasing, the sequence defined by $a_n = \frac {f(n)} {g(n)}$ diverges, and $f \neq \Omega(g)$ where $ f = \Omega(g) \iff \exists c \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \exists N \in \mathbb{R}^{+}\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{+} x>N \implies g(x) \le c \cdot f(x)$. I was wondering if anyone could think of a simple example of this, or if anyone could formalize a certain idea I had: I had an idea of how to construct $f$ and $g$ but couldn't formalize my idea into a definition; my idea is something like the below where $f$ is some parabola and $g$ is like a staircase (the "vertical" parts of $g$ aren't supposed to go straight up or backwards, which would violate the vertical line test, but rather accelerate forward at a steep angle):

I thought this would work because $f \over g$ continually oscillates up to $1$, so it doesn't converge, and because the ratio of the horizontal parts of the staircase to the parabola get bigger as $x$ increases, there cannot exist a fixed constant such that multiplying $g$ by this constant makes it exceed $f$ for all sufficiently large $x$. However, I couldn't find a closed form expression, or formal recursive definition, for $f$ and $g$ as I was thinking of them.
So, does anyone have a simple example of $f$ and $g$ with this property, or can anyone formalize the example I gave?

By diverges, do you mean diverges to $+\infty?$ Because it seems like you can get it by having odd terms go to zero and even terms go to $+\infty.$

@ThomasAndrews I mean diverge in the sense "doesn't converge". Also, maybe I am misunderstanding your schema of having odd terms go to zero and even terms go to $+ \infty$, but it seems like the function wouldn't be strictly increasing then?

Yes you can construct a piecewise function. But finding a natural function that does the trick is... tricky.

@AdamRubinson any ideas on how to formally define the piecewise function for $g$ which I attempted to describe?

I mean the ration goes to zero when odd and $\infty$ for even. Something like $f(n)=(n!)^2$ and $g(2n)=(2n+1)(2n)!^2$ and $g(2n+1)=(2n+1)(2n)!^2+1.$

@ThomasAndrews in your example, does the ratio not go to zero as well when $n$ is even?

Yeah, I may have gotten ahead of myself there.  If $f(n)$ grows really fast, then let $g(n)=nf(n)$ when $n$ odd and $f(n)/n$ when $n$ even. But you need to specify a function which grows fast to make $g$ also be increasing.

I think $f(n)=(n!)^2$ and $g(n)=f(n)/n$ when $n$ even and $nf(n)$ when $n$ odd works.

I think in your diagram you have $f$ and $g$ the wrong way round.
The following almost does the trick:
$g(x)=x$
For each $n\in\mathbb{N},\ f(x) = 2^{n^2}\ $ if $x\in \left(2^{n^2},2^{(n+1)^2}\right]$
This guarantees that no constant $c$ exists.
This is not continuous, although your question does not require continuity, so this is not a problem. But it is not strictly increasing, which is a very minor issue, because we just have to change each section/piece of the function to be ever so slightly increasing, without changing what the function looks like (i.e. whilst maintaining that $f$ is strictly increasing). You can even make this function continuous, or even differentiable if you join each piece up carefully enough.

In the image $f > g$ everywhere, so that wouldn't work. But if you interchange the two, then after every step, $f$ rises to nearly meet $g$, but over the course of a step, $f/g$ can go arbitrarily small for large intervals, and this would work. We can also make the 'jumps' higher than $g$, so that $\limsup a_n = \infty$.
To this end, fix an increasing $g$, and take $\xi_i$ to be an increasing sequence, with $\xi_1 = 1$. I'll only define $f$ on the naturals, but one can extend it to the reals by interpolating linearly.
For each $i$, define $ f(\xi_i) = g(\xi_i)\log g(\xi_i), $ and for each $k \le \xi_{i+1} - \xi_i - 1,$ define $f(\xi_i + k) = g(\xi_i) \log g(\xi_i)  + k/(g(\xi_{i+1}))$. Then we have $$\zeta_i := \inf_{n \in [\xi_i:\xi_{i+1} - 1]} f(n)/g(n) \le \frac{g(\xi_i)\log g(\xi_i)}{g(\xi_{i+1} - 1)} + \frac{\xi_{i+1} - \xi_i - 1}{g(\xi_{i+1}-1) g(\xi_{i+1})},$$ and $$ \eta_i := \sup_{n \in [\xi_i:\xi_{i+1} - 1]} f(n)/g(n) \ge  \log g(\xi_i).$$
Now, its a question of picking $g, \{\xi_i\}$ such that $\zeta_i \to 0$ and $\eta_i \to \infty$. Just picking $g$ to be increasing ensures that $\eta_i \to \infty$. Further, the second term in $\zeta_i$ goes to $0$ if $g(n) \gg \sqrt{n}.$ So really the question becomes to find an increasing $\xi_i, g$ such that $g(\xi_i) \log g(\xi_i) \ll g(\xi_{i+1} - 1)$. Adam's example of $\xi_i = 2^{i^2}, g(n) = n$ works for this. You could also take $g$ growing quickly, e.g., $g(n) = 2^{n^2},$ and $\xi_i = 2i$, in which case $\zeta_i \le (2^{4i^2} \mathrm{poly}(i))/2^{4i^2 + 2i + 1} \le \mathrm{poly}(i)2^{-2i}.$

Let $f(n)=n^{2n}$ and $g(n)=n^{2n+(-1)^n}.$ $f$ is clear increasing. Also, $$g(n+1)\geq (n+1)^{2n+1}>n^{2n+1}\geq g(n).$$ So $g$ is increasing.
But $$\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=\begin{cases}n&n\text{ odd}\\ \frac1n&n\text{ even}\end{cases},$$ so it doesn't converge. But the fact that it converges to $0$ for $n$ odd means $f(n)$ is not $\Omega(g).$

As noted in comments, this doesn't actually define $g$ on the reals, but we can fix that by interpolating the function linearly. The real problem is $x^x$ is not increasing on $(0,1),$ so you really need $f(n)=(n+1)^{2n}$ and then $g(n)=(n+1)^{2n\pm1}.$

A closed form answer defined on the reals would be $$f(n)=(n+1)^{4n}, g(n)=(n+1)^{4n+\cos\pi n}.$$
The $4n$ makes it really easy to prove the derivative of $g$ is positive.

$g$ is not a function $\mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}^+$.

Didn't notice that, since $n$ is usually used for integers only. But you can easily interpolate this with linear values, or replace $(-1)^n$ with $\sin n\pi.$ @aschepler

Yeah, we're talking about both a function on real numbers and the sequence from sampling it at integer arguments.
